# Using console_scripts entry_points with pythonw?

Tags: python, pyqt, setuptools, pythonw

I've created a python library with a GUI component.  I'm creating a command line launcher using the `console_scripts` feature of `setuptools`.  Currently, when I launch the tool using the `console_scripts` launcher, it also brings up a command shell because it's being launched with `python.exe`.  Is there a way to use the `console_scripts` feature but launch the script with `pythonw` instead so that no command shell appears?

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mytool',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['mytool=mytool.cli:main'],
    },
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gui_scripts` instead of `console_scripts`.

See [this page](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) for more info.